# How can I make a copy of device/socket file

Tags: linux, unix

I can know inode of device/socket with stat, so seems like I can somehow "copy" this file for backup. Of course the solution is "dd", but I have no idea what can I do if the device is infinity (like the random one). And can I just copy the inode somehow?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to make a backup of? The data on the device? Backing up the device itself doesn't make much physical sense...

Comment: I want to know how can I fetch the data from those types of files and then backup them. But if it's not possible to backup the information (and I will be really happy if you tell me why), I've to make something like a mirror of those files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are referred to as "special files" or "special nodes".  Copying their contents doesn't make sense, as the contents are generated in one way or another programatically by the kernel as needed.

Programs like "tar" know how to copy the contents of the inode, which will refer to the portion of the kernel that support each of these different nodes.  See the documentation of the "mknod" command for some more details.

Comment: And so, can you say, how does this programs work? Seems like this is what I need. Thank you. UPD: I looked through the manpage, but didn't understand, how can I know major and minor numbers of existing device file.

Comment: I understand that I can create a named pipe using mkfifo. (seen as prw-... in ls -l). Is there a similar command for creating a socket file? socket files are seen as (srw-... in ls -l) & not same as fifo.

Comment: So if I want to create a full backup of a folder and the folder contains a .socket file, there is no way to do it then? I mean I'm not expecting the .socket file to "work" on a different computer, I simply want to be able to restore it to the original location in case I ever have to roll back.

Answer (score 3):

And if you need one-liner to copy device nodes with tar, here it is:

```
cd /dev && tar -cpf- sda* | tar -xf- -C /some/destination/path/
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the major and minor number of the device file you need to copy then use mknod to create the device file with the same major and minor number.  Major number is used for a program to access to kernel device switch table and calling the proper kernel function (usually device drive).  Minor number is used as a parameter for calling those functions (like different density, disk, .... etc).

Answer (score 0):

24 July 2022

There is one legitimate use case for copying (archiving) a socket.

I have a program that gathers and summarizes attribute data in a file system tree.  In order to regression test, I created a directory that contains one example of every type of file the program might encounter.  I run my program on this directory to test it whenever I alter the code.

It is necessary to backup this directory along with other more valuable data, and it is necessary to restore it, should the storage device fail.

`tar` is the program of choice, and of course `tar` can not archive a socket.  Doing so in most situations is senseless - any program that uses the socket will have to delete it and recreate it before use.

In the case of the test directory, there is one named socket, for it is possible that my program will encounter such things and it needs to correctly gather attributes for a complete summary.

As noted by others, that socket is not useful for anything directly.  It does, however, occupy a little storage space, much as an empty file occupies storage space.  That is why you can see it in the directory listing.

You can copy it successfully with the command:

```
cp -ar --parents <path> <backup_device_directory>
```

and restore it with:

```
cp -ar --parents <backup_device_directory>/<path> <directory>
```

The socket is not useful for anything *except* probing its attributes with a program during a regression test.

Archiving it saves the trouble of having to remember to recreate it after a restoration.  The extra nuisance of archiving the sockets is easily codified in a script and forgotten.  That is what we all want - easy to use solutions whose implementation you can ignore after you have solved the problem.

Answer (score -4):

You can copy from a working system as below to some shared location between the machines and copy from the shared location to the other system.

Machine A

```
cp -rf /dev/SRC shared_directory
```

Machine B

```
cp -rf shared_directory /dev/
```

Comment: This was ages ago now, but this solution does not work to copy socket files.